# Most optimised and efficient way to fetch sql records

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have a website which displays the users information (mainly name and age) and i want to know what is the most optimised and efficient way to fetch all the records from the database .

Though i just started learning DBMS and Here is my 1st piece of code

```
    <?php     
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "simple_login";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }  
    $sql = "SELECT name,age from `members`";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);        
    for($i=1;$i<6;$i++)
    {
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $name=$row['name'];
    $age=$row['age'];
    ?>
    <div class="container">
        <h4>Name : <? echo $name; ?></h4>
        <h4>Age : <? echo $age; ?></h4>
    </div>
```

But i am not sure if it would be the best way to fetch and display records. 
Besides this what if i want to display this same information on different  pages , do i have to copy all this every time again and again?

Comment: sidenote: if that's your full/real code, it's missing a few braces `}`.

Comment: well its just to display records to a certain extent.

Comment: @Fred-ii- its not my full code though , its just a piece of it

Comment: @chris85 what if i have to slightly modify my query on other pages?

Comment: @chris85 Thanks mate :) , just one more thing do i have to copy the whole code every time when some modifications in the query is guaranteed?

Comment: @chris85 No i mean suppose i have 5 different pages, and each page displays the same code with slightly modified queries(like page 1 contains all the record with age<18 ,page 2 containing age <21 and so on) , so should i copy the whole code every time?

Comment: You could define `$sql` on every page and then have this check like the `limit` approach.. I've moved previous comments to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing `if ($result->num_rows > 0) {` multiple times is inefficient, as is querying for all records then only using 6. Loop the fetch after you check for a return and `limit` your query.

```
$limit = empty($limit) ? 6 : (int) $limit;
$sql = "SELECT name,age from `members` limit $limit";
$result = $conn->query($sql);        
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

With this approach on other pages you can do:

```
<?php
$limit = 10;
include 'my_member_script.php';
```

which will output 10 members.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate !